# SSRS Rest API - Get Extension Settings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get the Subscription details through SSRS Rest API. Below is the API request.

```
Url: http://{URI-host}/reports/api/v2.0/Subscriptions
HttpMethod: GET
```

It is returning me a json with the subscription details. But I can't find the e-mail related details like To, Subject etc in the response. the response is as below.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://{URI-host}/reports/api/v2.0/$metadata#Subscriptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "8af9701b-1cae-4c7e-be36-5768f6412be5",
            "Owner": "pc\\userpower",
            "IsDataDriven": false,
            "Description": "Test",
            "Report": "/Folder/ReportName",
            "IsActive": true,
            "EventType": "TimedSubscription",
            "Schedule": {
                "ScheduleID": null,
                "Definition": {
                    "StartDateTime": "2020-02-29T02:00:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "EndDateSpecified": false,
                    "Recurrence": {
                        "MinuteRecurrence": null,
                        "DailyRecurrence": {
                            "DaysInterval": 1
                        },
                        "WeeklyRecurrence": null,
                        "MonthlyRecurrence": null,
                        "MonthlyDOWRecurrence": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "ScheduleDescription": "At 2:00 AM every day, starting 2/29/2020",
            "LastRunTime": null,
            "LastStatus": "New Subscription",
            "DataQuery": null,
            "ExtensionSettings": null,
            "DeliveryExtension": "Report Server Email",
            "LocalizedDeliveryExtensionName": "E-Mail",
            "ModifiedBy": "pc\\userpower",
            "ModifiedDate": "2020-02-27T09:28:36.103Z",
            "ParameterValues": [
                {
                    "Name": "ProjectID",
                    "Value": "2",
                    "IsValueFieldReference": false
                },
                {
                    "Name": "UserID",
                    "Value": "10",
                    "IsValueFieldReference": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

if you notice "ExtensionSettings" is always null.

Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same exact issue.  So far, the only way found to get this info, is to individually call the Subscription GET.  The get on an ID will return the ExtensionSettings.

```
http://{URI-host}/reports/api/v2.0/Subscriptions(8af9701b-1cae-4c7e-be36-5768f6412be5)
```

Comment: There are no other possible solutions? That sucks performance if you have many subscriptions to check